# CentOS 6.9 mysql el6 installation forced to el7

Tags: mysql

My server is CentOS 6.9, trying to install mysql server. Installation failed with error package as shown.

```
---> Package mysql-community-server.x86_64 0:5.7.20-1.el6 will be updated
---> Package mysql-community-server.x86_64 0:5.7.20-1.el7 will be an update
```

I think the above line forced my installation to CentOS 7, which cause the error package.

```
[chaoyou@YMYG ~]$ sudo yum install mysql-community-server
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.aliyun.com
 * epel: mirrors.tongji.edu.cn
 * extras: mirrors.aliyun.com
 * updates: mirrors.aliyun.com
 * webtatic: sp.repo.webtatic.com
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql-community-server.x86_64 0:5.7.20-1.el6 will be updated
---> Package mysql-community-server.x86_64 0:5.7.20-1.el7 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: mysql-community-common(x86-64) = 5.7.20-1.el7 for package: mysql-community-server-5.7.20-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: systemd for package: mysql-community-server-5.7.20-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: systemd for package: mysql-community-server-5.7.20-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.15)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-server-5.7.20-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.17)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-server-5.7.20-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libsasl2.so.3()(64bit) for package: mysql-community-server-5.7.20-1.el7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql-community-common.x86_64 0:5.7.20-1.el6 will be updated
---> Package mysql-community-common.x86_64 0:5.7.20-1.el7 will be an update
---> Package mysql-community-server.x86_64 0:5.7.20-1.el7 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: systemd for package: mysql-community-server-5.7.20-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: systemd for package: mysql-community-server-5.7.20-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.15)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-server-5.7.20-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.17)(64bit) for package: mysql-community-server-5.7.20-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libsasl2.so.3()(64bit) for package: mysql-community-server-5.7.20-1.el7.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: mysql-community-server-5.7.20-1.el7.x86_64 (mysql57-community)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.15)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-server-5.7.20-1.el7.x86_64 (mysql57-community)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.17)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-server-5.7.20-1.el7.x86_64 (mysql57-community)
           Requires: systemd
Error: Package: mysql-community-server-5.7.20-1.el7.x86_64 (mysql57-community)
           Requires: libsasl2.so.3()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Comment: End up installing mysql5.6